# ReactiveX (Rx) - Detecting Long Press Events

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, rxjs, rx-py

I am wondering what is the canonical approach to solve the following problem in Rx: Say I have two observables, `mouse_down` and `mouse_up`, whose elements represent mouse button presses. In a very simplistic scenario, if I wanted to detect a long press, I could do it the following way (in this case using RxPy, but conceptually the same in any Rx implementation):

```
mouse_long_press = mouse_down.delay(1000).take_until(mouse_up).repeat()
```

However, problems arise when we need to hoist some information from the `mouse_down` observable to the `mouse_up` observable. For example, consider if the elements of the observable stored information about which mouse button was pressed. Obviously, we would only want to pair `mouse_down` with `mouse_up` of the corresponding button. One solution that I came up with is this:

```
mouse_long_press = mouse_down.select_many(lambda x:
    rx.Observable.just(x).delay(1000)\
        .take_until(mouse_up.where(lambda y: x.button == y.button))
)
```

If there is a more straight forward solution, I would love to hear it - but as far as I can tell this works. However, things get more complicated, if we also want to detect how far the mouse has moved between `mouse_down` and `mouse_up`. For this we need to introduce a new observable `mouse_move`, which carries information about the mouse position.

```
mouse_long_press = mouse_down.select_many(lambda x:
    mouse_move.select(lambda z: distance(x, z) > 100).delay(1000)\
        .take_until(mouse_up.where(lambda y: x.button == y.button))
)
```

However, this is pretty much where I get stuck. Whenever a button is held down longer than 1 second, I get a bunch of boolean values. However, I only want to detect a long press when all of them are false, which sounds like the perfect case for the [all operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/all.html). It feels like there's only a small step missing, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work so far. Perhaps I am also doing things in a backwards way. Looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't `mouse_up` event contain data about cursor position?

Comment: @ErykNapierała Yes, however it can take an arbitrarily long time for the `mouse_up` to occur, but the long press should be triggered a fixed amount of time after the `mouse_down`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess I found a possible answer. RxPy has a `take_with_time` operator, which works for this purpose. Not really as straight-forward as I was hoping for (not sure if the `take_with_time` is avaliable in other Rx implementations).

```
mouse_long_press = mouse_down.select_many(lambda x:
    mouse_moves.take_with_time(1000).all(lambda z: distance(x, z) < 100)\
        .take_until(mouse_up.where(lambda y: x.button == y.button))
)
```

I will leave the question open for now in case somebody has a better suggestion.

Comment: It appears that RxPy is the [only implementation with takeWithTime](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html), and the ReactiveX site doesn't have any docs on it yet.

Comment: RxJava has an overload of `take` which works with time [take(long, TimeUnit)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#take%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Comment: @SamuelGruetter Interesting, thanks! I have looked for alternative ways of getting this behavior using more "standard" Rx operators, but so far this seems to be the most straight forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach the problem differently, by creating a stream of *mouse presses* with length information, and filtering that for presses longer than 1s.

---

**First** let's assume that you only have one mouse button. Merge the `mouse_up` and `mouse_down` streams and assign time intervals between them with the `time_interval()` operator. You will get a stream of *intervals since previous event*, along with the event itself. Assuming your mouse-ups and mouse-downs alternate, this means your events now are:

(down + time since last up), (up + time since last down), (down + time since last up) ...

Now, simply filter for `x.value.type == "up" and x.interval > datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)`

(You can also validate this with `pairwise()`, which always gives you the current + previous event, so you can check that the previous one is down and the current one is up.)

---

**Second**, add the mouse movement information, using the `window()` operator.

(This part is untested, I'm going off the docs of how it's supposed to behave, but the docs aren't very clear. So YMMV. )

The idea is that you can collect sequences of events from an observable, separated into groups based on another observable. From the docs:
[image: window(window_openings)]
The `window_openings` observable is going to be the merged up/down stream, or the interval stream, whichever is more convenient. Then you can `flat_map()` (or `select_many`, which is the same thing) the result and work out the distance in whichever way you like.

Again, you should end up with a stream of *distances between up/down events*. Then you can `zip()` this stream with the interval stream, at which point you can filter for up events and get both time and distance until the previous down.

---

**Third**, what if you are getting events for multiple mouse buttons?

Simply use `group_by()` operator to split into per-button streams and proceed as above.

Full code below:

```
Event = collections.NamedTuple("Event", "event interval distance")

def sum_distance(move_stream):
    # put your distance calculation here; something like:
    return move_stream.pairwise().reduce(lambda acc, (a, b): acc + distance(a, b), 0)

def mouse_press(updown_stream):
    # shared stream for less duplication
    shared = updown_stream.share()
    intervals = shared.time_interval()  # element is: (interval=timedelta, value=original event)
    distances = mouse_move.window(shared).flat_map(sum_distance)
    zipped = intervals.zip(distances, lambda i, d: \
        Event(i.value, i.interval, d) )

mouse_long_press = (
    # merge the mouse streams
    rx.Observable.merge(mouse_up, mouse_down)
    # separate into streams for each button
    .group_by(lambda x: x.button)
    # create per-button event streams per above and merge results back
    .flat_map(mouse_press)
    # filter by event type and length
    .filter(lambda ev: ev.event.type == "up" and ev.interval >= datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
)
```

Comment: ...and of course, after finishing the answer, I finally realized that you want the event to fire *after one second* regardless of when the mouse_up comes. Well.